# MySQL - Select percentage with multiple columns

Tags: mysql, percentage

## Hey

I've got a table similar to the image  below

[image]

My goal is to write a query which should output the id, and a column named `pvt`, for each organisation (i.e. each row in that spreadsheet)

The value the `pvt` column should be based on the following logic:

If an organisation's percentage of deliveries:

1. Are made using cars, at a rate of *over* **90%** in comparison to other vehicles, then `pvt` should be `Cars`
2. Are made using vans, at a rate of *over* **90%** in comparison to other vehicles, then `pvt` should be `Vans`
3. Are made using coaches, at a rate of *over* **90%** in comparison to other vehicles, then `pvt` should be `Coaches`
4. Are made using coaches, at a rate of *over* **90%** in comparison to other vehicles, then `pvt` should be `Trucks`

If none of those vehicle columns amount to **90%** of a organisation's deliveries, then

1. If `Cars` + `Vans` amount to **90%**, then `pvt` should be `Cars & Vans`
2. If `Coaches` + `Trucks` amount to **90%**, then `pvt` should be `Coaches & Trucks`

As a fall back, anything else should render the `pvt` as `Mixed`,

If I were to run my desired query, I would get something like this:

[image]

Thanks, all.

Comment: I think we'd need a more explicit table schema to make any recommendations.  Seems to me, your starting table is very not-normalized, so it's not going to be an intuitive solution...

Comment: Added an image.. I don't have access to the DB atm but it should make sense in combination with the question, hopefully.

Comment: That's a pretty scary schema... do the individual rows represent anything at all?

Comment: Also, how would it be possible for more than 1 vehicle type to be > 90%?  I must be misunderstanding your desired output.  Perhaps you should edit your question to include your desired output.

Comment: @Sturgus I feel I may have been ambiguous with detail, but there are unique identifiers and other fields in place in the rows too. Each row represents an organisations, the fields apparent in the question simply contain information on the vehicles used by those organisations

Comment: @Sturgus With regards to both being > 90%, I suppose the spec means if 2 vehicle types are exactly the same number, with that number being 90% or greater of the total sum of all vehicle types.

Comment: @Sturgus my answer yields the result I'm looking for - I doubt it's the most efficient way to do it, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be done like this,

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN ((truck / t.vehicles) * 100) > 90 THEN 'Truck'
WHEN ((van / t.vehicles) * 100) > 90 THEN 'Van'
WHEN ((coach / t.vehicles) * 100) > 90 THEN 'Coach'
WHEN (((truck/ t.vehicles) * 100) + ((van / t.vehicles) * 100)) > 90 THEN 'Truck and Van'
WHEN (((coach / t.vehicles) * 100) + ((lorry/ t.vehicles) * 100)) > 90 THEN 'Lorry and Coach'
ELSE 'Mixed'
END AS `pvt`

FROM Table f
INNER JOIN (SELECT t.id,SUM(van) + SUM(truck) + SUM(coach) + SUM(lorry) AS `vehicles` FROM Table t GROUP BY t.id) t ON t.id=f.id
```

Comment: Although, I still can't picture your schema well, it seems fishy that you do a `GROUP BY id` with a sum.  That insinuates that each row does not represent a single organization.  Though, it also seems clear that you're working with two tables here instead of one (Table `f` and table `t`)

Comment: To successfully give you advice on how to best accomplish this, we need to see your id's and both tables with a tiny bit of sample data and a sample desired output.

Comment: @Sturgus in this context I'm using two tables for the purposes of the query, but they're both still referring to `Table` i.e. the same table

Comment: @Sturgus I'll re-present the question in a moment